# After a process why Memory continuously stay up in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm using Rails 4 with Ruby 2.1.0. I have a code which taking about 2 GB of memory to complete process, but problem is after finish process...why is memory usage still up?

I also assign `nil` to variable after used which save 300 MB but still large amount of memory using by Ruby process.

Here is sample code to reproduce the problem:

```
def download_data(params, options = {})
    $file_name = ''
    portfolio_names = Portfolio.get_names
    building_names = Building.get_names
    tenant_names = Tenant.get_names
    meter_names = Meter.get_meter_names

    @portfolio_info, @building_info, @tenant_info, @meter_id, @from_date, @to_date = params[:portfolio_name], params[:building_name], params[:tenant_name], params[:meter_id], params[:from_date], params[:to_date]

    @from_date = DateTime.parse(@from_date).to_i
    @to_date = DateTime.parse(@to_date).to_i

    @building_f_name = building_names["#{@building_info}"]
    unless params[:fields].nil?
      @fields = params[:fields].split('_')
      @columns = []
      @fields.each do |f|
        if f.length > 0
          @columns << MeterData.new.show_real_value_of_meter_data_field_revert(f).to_sym
        end
      end
      @columns << 'date_time'.to_sym
      @columns << 'tenant'.to_sym
      @columns << 'meter_id'.to_sym
    else
      @columns = [:id, :date_time, :w3pht, :whintvlrec, :w__3phmaxavgdmd, :tenant, :meter_id]
    end


    #### database fetch ###########
    @meter_data = MeterData.find_by_sql("SELECT tenant, meter_id, SUM(van) as van, SUM(vbn) as vbn,
                                           SUM(vcn) as vcn, SUM(ia) as ia, SUM(ib) as ib, SUM(ic) as ic,
                                           SUM(w3pht) as w3pht, SUM(pf3pht) as pf3pht, SUM(f) as f,
                                           SUM(whrec) as whrec, SUM(whtot) as whtot, SUM(varhrec) as varhrec,
                                           SUM(varhtot) as varhtot, SUM(whintvlrec) as whintvlrec,
                                           SUM(whintvldel) as whintvldel, SUM(w__phavg) as w__phavg,
                                           SUM(var__3phavg) as var__3phavg, SUM(w_3phavg) as w_3phavg,
                                           SUM(var_3phavg) as var_3phavg, SUM(phai) as phai, SUM(phbi) as phbi,
                                           SUM(phci) as phci, SUM(w__3phmaxavgdmd) as w__3phmaxavgdmd,
                                           MAX(w__3phmaxavgdmd) as w__3phmaxavgdmd_max, SUM(var__3phmaxavgdmd) as var__3phmaxavgdmd,
                                           SUM(w_3phmaxavgdmd) as w_3phmaxavgdmd, SUM(var_3phmaxavgdmd) as var_3phmaxavgdmd,
                                           date_time FROM `meter_data` WHERE (`date_time_i` >= #{@from_date} AND `date_time_i` <= #{@to_date}
                                           AND building = '#{@building_info}') GROUP by tenant, meter_id, date_time
                                           ORDER BY `meter_data`.`date_time_i` ASC")
    sleep 0.5
    @meter_sum = MeterData.find_by_sql("SELECT meter_id, SUM(van) as van, SUM(vbn) as vbn, SUM(vcn) as vcn,
                                                    SUM(ia) as ia, SUM(ib) as ib, SUM(ic) as ic, SUM(w3pht) as w3pht,
                                                    SUM(pf3pht) as pf3pht, SUM(f) as f, SUM(whrec) as whrec,
                                                    SUM(whtot) as whtot, SUM(varhrec) as varhrec, SUM(varhtot) as varhtot,
                                                    SUM(whintvlrec) as whintvlrec, SUM(whintvldel) as whintvldel,
                                                    SUM(w__phavg) as w__phavg, SUM(var__3phavg) as var__3phavg,
                                                    SUM(w_3phavg) as w_3phavg, SUM(var_3phavg) as var_3phavg,
                                                    SUM(phai) as phai, SUM(phbi) as phbi, SUM(phci) as phci,
                                                    SUM(w__3phmaxavgdmd) as w__3phmaxavgdmd, MAX(w__3phmaxavgdmd) as w__3phmaxavgdmd_max,
                                                    SUM(var__3phmaxavgdmd) as var__3phmaxavgdmd, SUM(w_3phmaxavgdmd) as w_3phmaxavgdmd,
                                                    SUM(var_3phmaxavgdmd) as var_3phmaxavgdmd, date_time FROM `meter_data`
                                                    WHERE (`date_time_i` >= #{@from_date} AND `date_time_i` <= #{@to_date} AND building = '#{@building_info}')
                                                    GROUP by meter_id ORDER BY `meter_data`.`date_time_i` ASC")
    @meter_data_max = MeterData.find_by_sql("SELECT tenant, meter_id, MAX(w__3phmaxavgdmd) as w__3phmaxavgdmd,
                                               date_time FROM `meter_data` WHERE (`date_time_i` >= #{@from_date} AND `date_time_i` <= #{@to_date}
                                               AND building = '#{@building_info}') GROUP by tenant, meter_id
                                               ORDER BY `meter_data`.`date_time_i` ASC")
    sleep 0.5
    @uniq_meter_id = MeterData.select(:meter_id).where("`date_time_i` >= #{@from_date} AND `date_time_i` <= #{@to_date} AND building = '#{@building_info}'").uniq(:meter_id)
    #### database fetch ###########

    p = Axlsx::Package.new
    wb = p.workbook
    wb.styles do |s|

      styles_hash  = AxlsxStylesHash.get s

      wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Building data details") do |sheet|
        $row_num = 0
        meter_extra = MeterExtra.new

        columns_ = []; @columns.each { |s| columns_ << "#{s}_".to_s }

        sheet.add_row []
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.add_row ["Building report of #{@building_f_name}   #{@from_date} to #{@to_date}"], :style => styles_hash[:heading_cell]
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.add_row []
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.add_row []
        $row_num += 1

        sheet.merge_cells("A2:Q2")

        new_columns_ = []
        new_columns_ <<  "Date & Time" if columns_.include?('date_time_')
        new_columns_ <<  "Building" if columns_.include?('building_')
        new_columns_ <<  "Tenant" if columns_.include?('tenant_')
        new_columns_ <<  "Meter ID" if columns_.include?('meter_id_')
        new_columns_ <<  "Meter Name" if columns_.include?('meter_id_')
        new_columns_ <<  "van" if columns_.include?('van_')
        new_columns_ <<  "vbn" if columns_.include?('vbn_')
        new_columns_ <<  "vcn" if columns_.include?('vcn_')
        new_columns_ <<  "ia" if columns_.include?('ia_')
        new_columns_ <<  "ib" if columns_.include?('ib_')
        new_columns_ <<  "ic" if columns_.include?('ic_')
        new_columns_ <<  "w3pht" if columns_.include?('w3pht_')
        new_columns_ <<  "pf3pht" if columns_.include?('pf3pht_')
        new_columns_ <<  "f" if columns_.include?('f_')
        new_columns_ <<  "whrec" if columns_.include?('whrec_')
        new_columns_ <<  "whtot" if columns_.include?('whtot_')
        new_columns_ <<  "varhrec" if columns_.include?('varhrec_')
        new_columns_ <<  "varhtot" if columns_.include?('varhtot_')
        new_columns_ <<  "whintvlrec" if columns_.include?('whintvlrec_')
        new_columns_ <<  "whintvldel" if columns_.include?('whintvldel_')
        new_columns_ <<  "w+phavg" if columns_.include?('w__phavg_')
        new_columns_ <<  "var+3phavg" if columns_.include?('var__3phavg_')
        new_columns_ <<  "w-3phavg" if columns_.include?('w_3phavg_')
        new_columns_ <<  "var-3phavg" if columns_.include?('var_3phavg_')
        new_columns_ <<  "phai" if columns_.include?('phai_')
        new_columns_ <<  "phbi" if columns_.include?('phbi_')
        new_columns_ <<  "phci" if columns_.include?('phci_')
        new_columns_ <<  "w+3phmaxavgdmd" if columns_.include?('w__3phmaxavgdmd_')
        new_columns_ <<  "var+3phmaxavgdmd" if columns_.include?('var__3phmaxavgdmd_')
        new_columns_ <<  "w-3phmaxavgdmd" if columns_.include?('w_3phmaxavgdmd_')
        new_columns_ <<  "var-3phmaxavgdmd" if columns_.include?('var_3phmaxavgdmd_')

        sheet.add_row new_columns_, :style => styles_hash[:green_bold_border_cell]
        $row_num += 1
        t = 1; @meter_data.each do |m|
          new_columns_data = []
          if columns_.include?('date_time_')
            m_date_time = m['date_time']
            new_columns_data << ( m_date_time.nil? ? '--' : m_date_time)
          end
          if columns_.include?('building_')
            m_building = m_building
            new_columns_data << ( m_building.nil? ? '--' : building_names["#{m_building}"])
          end
          if columns_.include?('tenant_')
            m_tenant = m['tenant']
            new_columns_data << ( m_tenant.nil? ? '--' : tenant_names["#{m_tenant}"])
          end
          if columns_.include?('meter_id_')
            m_meter_id = m['meter_id']
            new_columns_data << ( m_meter_id.nil? ? '--' : m_meter_id)
          end
          if columns_.include?('meter_id_')
            m_meter_id = m['meter_id']
            new_columns_data << ( meter_extra.get_meter_name(m_meter_id.nil? ? '--' : m_meter_id) )
          end
          if columns_.include?('van_')
            m_van = m.van
            new_columns_data << ( m_van.nil? ? '--' : m_van )
          end
          if columns_.include?('vbn_')
            m_vbn = m.vbn
            new_columns_data << ( m_vbn.nil? ? '--' : m_vbn )
          end
          if columns_.include?('vcn_')
            m_vcn = m.vcn
            new_columns_data << ( m_vcn.nil? ? '--' : m_vcn )
          end
          if columns_.include?('ia_')
            m_ia = m.ia
            new_columns_data << ( m_ia.nil? ? '--' : m_ia )
          end
          if columns_.include?('ib_')
            m_ib = m.ib
            new_columns_data << ( m_ib.nil? ? '--' : m_ib )
          end
          if columns_.include?('ic_')
            m_ic = m.ic
            new_columns_data << ( m_ic.nil? ? '--' : m_ic )
          end
          if columns_.include?('w3pht_')
            m_w3pht = m.w3pht
            new_columns_data << ( m_w3pht.nil? ? '--' : m_w3pht )
          end
          if columns_.include?('pf3pht_')
            m_pf3pht = m.pf3pht
            new_columns_data << ( m_pf3pht.nil? ? '--' : m_pf3pht )
          end
          if columns_.include?('f_')
            m_f = m.f
            new_columns_data << ( m_f.nil? ? '--' : m_f )
          end
          if columns_.include?('whrec_')
            m_whrec = m.whrec
            new_columns_data << ( m_whrec.nil? ? '--' : m_whrec )
          end
          if columns_.include?('whtot_')
            m_whtot = m.whtot
            new_columns_data << ( m_whtot.nil? ? '--' : m_whtot )
          end
          if columns_.include?('varhrec_')
            m_varhrec = m.varhrec
            new_columns_data << ( m_varhrec.nil? ? '--' : m_varhrec )
          end
          if columns_.include?('varhtot_')
            m_varhtot = m.varhtot
            new_columns_data << ( m_varhtot.nil? ? '--' : m_varhtot )
          end
          if columns_.include?('whintvlrec_')
            m_whintvlrec = m.whintvlrec
            new_columns_data << ( m_whintvlrec.nil? ? '--' : m_whintvlrec )
          end
          if columns_.include?('whintvldel_')
            m_whintvldel = m.whintvldel
            new_columns_data << ( m_whintvldel.nil? ? '--' : m_whintvldel )
          end
          if columns_.include?('w__phavg_')
            m_w__phavg = m.w__phavg
            new_columns_data << ( m_w__phavg.nil? ? '--' : m_w__phavg )
          end
          if columns_.include?('var__3phavg_')
            m_var__3phavg = m.var__3phavg
            new_columns_data << ( m_var__3phavg.nil? ? '--' : m_var__3phavg )
          end
          if columns_.include?('w_3phavg_')
            m_w_3phavg = m.w_3phavg
            new_columns_data << ( m_w_3phavg.nil? ? '--' : m_w_3phavg )
          end
          if columns_.include?('var_3phavg_')
            m_var_3phavg = m.var_3phavg
            new_columns_data << ( m_var_3phavg.nil? ? '--' : m_var_3phavg )
          end
          if columns_.include?('phai_')
            m_phai = m.phai
            new_columns_data << ( m_phai.nil? ? '--' : m_phai )
          end
          if columns_.include?('phbi_')
            m_phbi = m.phbi
            new_columns_data << ( m_phbi.nil? ? '--' : m_phbi )
          end
          if columns_.include?('phci_')
            m_phci = m.phci
            new_columns_data << ( m_phci.nil? ? '--' : m_phci )
          end
          if columns_.include?('w__3phmaxavgdmd_')
            m_w__3phmaxavgdmd = m.w__3phmaxavgdmd
            new_columns_data << ( m_w__3phmaxavgdmd.nil? ? '--' : m_w__3phmaxavgdmd )
          end
          if columns_.include?('var__3phmaxavgdmd_')
            m_var__3phmaxavgdmd = m.var__3phmaxavgdmd
            new_columns_data << ( m_var__3phmaxavgdmd.nil? ? '--' : m_var__3phmaxavgdmd )
          end
          if columns_.include?('w_3phmaxavgdmd_')
            m_w_3phmaxavgdmd = m.w_3phmaxavgdmd
            new_columns_data << (m_w_3phmaxavgdmd.nil? ? '--' : m_w_3phmaxavgdmd )
          end
          if columns_.include?('var_3phmaxavgdmd_')
            m_var_3phmaxavgdmd = m.var_3phmaxavgdmd
            new_columns_data << ( m_var_3phmaxavgdmd.nil? ? '--' : m_var_3phmaxavgdmd )
          end

          if t == 1
            sheet.add_row new_columns_data , :style => styles_hash[:simple_green_cell], :widths=>[20]
          else
            sheet.add_row new_columns_data, :style => styles_hash[:simple_white_cell], :widths=>[20]
          end
          $row_num += 1
          t = 0 if t == 2
          t += 1
          puts $row_num
          m = nil
        end
        @meter_data = nil
        ## logo ##
        ReportBillLogo.put sheet, $row_num
        sheet = nil;
      end


      ## summary calculation ##
      wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Summary") do |sheet|
        $row_num = 0
        sheet.add_row []
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.add_row ["Summary report of #{@building_f_name}   #{@from_date} to #{@to_date}"], :style => styles_hash[:heading_cell]
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.add_row []
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.add_row []
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.merge_cells("A1:Q1")

        columns_ = []; @columns.each { |s| columns_ << "#{s}_".to_s }

        new_columns_ = []
        new_columns_ <<  "Meter ID"
        new_columns_ <<  "Meter Name"
        new_columns_ <<  "Max KW"

        sheet.add_row new_columns_, :style => styles_hash[:green_bold_border_cell]
        $row_num += 1

        t = 0
        @meter_data_max.each do |m|
          new_columns_data = []
          new_columns_data << m.meter_id
          new_columns_data << meter_names["#{m.meter_id}"]
          new_columns_data << ( m.w__3phmaxavgdmd.nil? ? '' : m.w__3phmaxavgdmd )

          if t == 1
            sheet.add_row new_columns_data, :style => styles_hash[:simple_green_cell], :widths=>[25]
          else
            sheet.add_row new_columns_data, :style => styles_hash[:simple_white_cell], :widths=>[25]
          end
          $row_num += 1
          t = 0 if t == 2
          t += 1
          m = nil;
        end
        ## logo ##
        ReportBillLogo.put sheet, $row_num
        sheet = nil
      end

      ## summary calculation ##

      ## summary calculation ##
      wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Energy consumed") do |sheet|
        $row_num = 0
        sheet.add_row []
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.add_row ["Energy consumed report of #{@building_f_name}   #{@from_date} to #{@to_date}"], :style => styles_hash[:heading_cell]
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.add_row []
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.add_row []
        $row_num += 1
        sheet.merge_cells("A2:Q2")

        engery = []
        @uniq_meter_id.each do |f|
          start = MeterData.find_by_sql("select whtot from meter_data where `date_time_i` >= #{@from_date} AND meter_id = '#{f.meter_id}' ORDER BY date_time_i ASC limit 1")
          eand  = MeterData.find_by_sql("select whtot from meter_data where `date_time_i` <= #{@from_date} AND meter_id = '#{f.meter_id}' ORDER BY date_time_i DESC limit 1")
          sleep 0.009
          begin
            engery << (eand.last.whtot.to_i - start.first.whtot.to_i)
          rescue
            engery << '--'
          end
          start = nil; eand = nil;
          f = nil;
        end
        columns_ = []; @columns.each { |s| columns_ << "#{s}_".to_s }
        new_columns_ = []
        new_columns_ <<  "Meter ID"
        new_columns_ <<  "Meter Name"
        new_columns_ <<  "Subtraction result"
        new_columns_ <<  "Aggregate result"
        sheet.add_row new_columns_, :style => styles_hash[:green_bold_border_cell]
        $row_num += 1
        flage = 0
        t = 0
        @meter_sum.each do |m|
          new_columns_data = []
          new_columns_data << m.meter_id
          new_columns_data << meter_names["#{m.meter_id}"]
          new_columns_data << engery[flage]
          new_columns_data << m.whintvlrec
          if t == 1
            sheet.add_row new_columns_data, :style => styles_hash[:simple_green_cell], :widths=>[25]
          else
            sheet.add_row new_columns_data, :style => styles_hash[:simple_white_cell], :widths=>[25]
          end
          $row_num += 1
          flage += 1
          t = 0 if t == 2
          t += 1
          m = nil
        end

        ## logo ##
        ReportBillLogo.put sheet, $row_num
        sheet = nil;
      end
    end

    $file_name = "tmp/#{@building_info} . #{@from_date} - #{@to_date} _ #{Time.new.to_i}.xlsx"
    p.serialize($file_name)
    p = nil; wb = nil;
    @meter_data = nil; @meter_data_max = nil; @meter_sum = nil;
    return $file_name
  end
# total records = 5, 00, 000
```

Comment: Have you been able to replicate the problem with a small sample of code that we can take a look at?

Comment: with small sample of code also working same. memory still stay up.

Comment: May we see what you're using for your sample code please?

Comment: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/9994a

Answer (score 0):

When ruby process is running out of memory it access a huge bit of memory from the system called heap slab. This big chunk is then internally divided into many small bits, which holds your variables and your code. When you assign nil to some variable, garbage collector will mark this small bit as empty, but the whole slab is never returned to the system until process is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is actually the problem that you're having, but there's a [known issue with Ruby 2.1.x's generational garbage collection](http://www.omniref.com/blog/blog/2014/03/27/ruby-garbage-collection-still-not-ready-for-production/) where allocated objects in memory that are supposed to be "short-lived" end up being accidentally promoted to "long-lived" instead, causing memory to bloat because the garbage collector doesn't run frequently enough to clean up these objects:

> Koichi Sasada, the author of the generational GC in Ruby 2.1:
>
> > “Some ‘short-lived’ young objects will be promoted to ‘old-gen’ accidentally….if such ‘short-lived’ objects consume huge memory we need to free such objects.”

A [current workaround](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7489813) that is being mentioned a lot right now in the Ruby community is to change a default Ruby setting in order to tell it to garbage collect more often:

> Expect memory doubling with Ruby 2.1.1. Not happy with that? You have 2 options:
>
> 1. Tune it down by reducing `RUBY_GC_HEAP_OLDOBJECT_LIMIT_FACTOR`. At `1` your memory consumption will be on par with 2.0. It ships with the `2` default.
> 2. Option 2, wait for a future release of Ruby, this will be fixed in 2.2 maybe even patched a bit more in 2.1.2 . See:
>
>    - https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9607 and
>    - http://vimeo.com/89491942 and
>    - https://speakerdeck.com/samsaffron/why-ruby-2-dot-1-excites-me